# Issue with DESfire EV1 wrapped APDU for PPS command while using javax.smartcardio

Tags: java, smartcard, mifare, apdu, baud-rate

I am writing a software in java, on the reader side, to communicate with a MiFare DESfire EV1 card.
I am using for this `javax.smartcardio`. I managed to create a channel and send wrapped APDU of native DESfire commands. For example I managed to read a file or even to authenticate.

What I have been struggling with, those last days, is trying to send a PPS command at level-4 to be able to set the Baud rate between the reader and the card.

The native PPS command is as follow:

```
DESFIRE command code 0xD0
DESFIRE command parameter 0x11 0x0A
```

If I am coherent with my previous technique to build ISO 7816-4 wrapped APDU, then it is supposed to look like this `0x90 0xD0 0x00 0x00 0x2 0x11 0x0A 0x00`.

Here is the response of this command:

```
SW1 : 0x91
DESFIRE response data : 0x1C
SW2 : none
```

`0x1C` stands for `ILLEGAL_COMMAND_CODE`; the syntax seems correct to me, why cannot I send this command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With APDU wrapping you can only wrap DESFire commands. The PPS command is part of the underlying ISO 14443-4 layer. In fact the PPS command is part of the initialization phase of the ISO 14443-4 transmission protocol. However, once you are at the point where you can transmit APDUs, the ISO 14443-4 transmission protocol (ISO-DEP / T=CL) has already been established. So at this point you cannot change any protocol parameters with the PPS command.

In general you can't change these parameters through `javax.smartcardio` unless the smartcard reader implements some specific interface for re-activation of the card with a different data rate.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Michael, I thought I could send the PPS at level 4.
What kind of smartcard reader implements such interface for re-activation of the card settings? I am playing with a reader from SpringCard. They provide an interface, but I can't reach 848 kbauds.

Comment: Springcard's Prox'n'Roll PC/SC should be fine. Consult the reader's manual and check if it provides any configuration registers to setup automatic baudrate handshake.